# How to combine two arrays and overwrite old property value with new changes

Tags: javascript

This is the new array I’m getting:

```
[
  {"Fields-0": false}
]
```

this is the current one:

```
[
  {"Fields-0": true},
  {"Fields-1": true}
]
```

and wanted to result like this:

```
[
  {"Fields-0": false},
  {"Fields-1": true}
]
```

I’ve tried:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = this.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};

var array3 = array1.concat(array2).unique();
```

but no luck

Comment: @Ajay has the correct answer for what you need. But the important question is why aren't you using an object for this data? Then you could simply update the appropriate key.

Comment: Agree. That data structure doesn't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var arr1=[
  {"Fields-0": false}
];

var arr2=[
  {"Fields-0": true},
  {"Fields-1": true}
];

for(var key2 in arr2){
   var arr2_el=arr2[key2];
   for(var key_el2 in arr2_el){
       for(var key1 in arr1){
             var arr1_el=arr1[key1];
             for(var key_el1 in arr1_el){
                if(key_el1==key_el2){
                   arr2_el[key_el2]=arr1_el[key_el1];
                }
             }
       }
   }
}
console.log(arr2);
```